# You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing your Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy my Rails app to my DigitalOcean server with

```
cap production deploy
```

But I'm getting an error,

```
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@178.62.204.53: bundle exit status: 16
bundle stdout: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

You have deleted from the Gemfile:
* rails-assets-angular-devise

You have changed in the Gemfile:
* rails-assets-angular-devise from `no specified source` to `rubygems repository
https://rubygems.org/, https://rails-assets.org/`
bundle stderr: Nothing written

SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 16
bundle stdout: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

You have deleted from the Gemfile:
* rails-assets-angular-devise

You have changed in the Gemfile:
* rails-assets-angular-devise from `no specified source` to `rubygems repository
https://rubygems.org/, https://rails-assets.org/`
bundle stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => bundler:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy@178.62.204.53: bundle exit status: 16
bundle stdout: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

You have deleted from the Gemfile:
* rails-assets-angular-devise

You have changed in the Gemfile:
* rails-assets-angular-devise from `no specified source` to `rubygems repository
https://rubygems.org/, https://rails-assets.org/`
bundle stderr: Nothing written
alucardu@alucardu-VirtualBox:~/sites/movieseat(Deploy) $ source "https://rails-assets.org" do
bash: https://rails-assets.org: No such file or directory
alucardu@alucardu-VirtualBox:~/sites/movieseat(Deploy) $   gem "rails-assets-angular-devise"
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command rails-assets-angular-devise
alucardu@alucardu-VirtualBox:~/sites/movieseat(Deploy) $ end
```

There is something wrong with my Gemfile and the Gemfile.lock and it has to do with `rails-assets-angular-devise` but I can't figure out how to fix it.

I've tried running `bundle install` on my server but still the same error. I've tried removing the Gemlock.file and doing `bundle install` on my local and then commiting it and pushing it to my deploy branch but still the same error.

This is the rails-assets-angular-devise part in the gemfile.

```
source "https://rails-assets.org" do
  gem "rails-assets-angular-devise"
end
```

Comment: It doesn't appear as though `rails-assets-angular-devise` is registered on https://rails-assets.org. The live search yields no results. However, `angular-devise` is listed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check bundler version on server in correctly gemset - probably you have old bundler version in your gemset or local gem (if you doesn't use rvm on server)

I have the same problem, steps to resolved it:

- login to server
- switch rvm to correctly for your application
- `$ gem update bundler`
- close ssh session and try again `cap [env] deploy`

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs due to different `bundler gem versions` on your deployment server and your development server. `bundler gem version` must be equal on the server and your development environment

once the same bundler version is installed on both the production and development environment then deploy again using:

```
cap production deploy
```

check bundler version using `gem info bundler` and install or uninstall version as per requirement

Install:

```
gem install bundler -v <bundler_version>
E.g.
gem install bundler -v 2.2.4
```

Uninstall:

```
gem uninstall bundler -v <bundler_version>
E.g.
gem uninstall bundler -v 2.2.4
```