# "Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app" installation of decdim on herouku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to install decidim (decidim.org) on herouku, I get this error when i make the deploy

```
remote: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
remote: your Gemfile. Run bundle install elsewhere and add the
remote: updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
remote:
remote: The gemspecs for path gems changed
remote: !
remote: ! Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote: !
remote: ! Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote: ! Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

this is the end lines of the deploy.

anyone has an answer for this issue? 
thanks

Comment: Have you done what the error says to do? Ran `bundle install` locally and make sure Gemfile.lock is added to version control?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11513623/1531971, https://stackoverflow.com/q/32380828/1531971, https://stackoverflow.com/q/40922424/1531971 (Otherwise you need to show how thesde refs are not related to your very common problem.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the quoted error message explains exactly how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder where you have your app and try typing the command: `bundle install` then try pushing to heroku afterwards.